# MenuItem. ColorFilter. Rounded background

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, android-vectordrawable

I use vector drawable for MenuItem.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Pen")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_pen)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}
```

I have changeable variable "color".
For Android version >= Lollipop I use setTin(color)

```
menuItem.getIcon().setTint(color);
```

For Android <= Lollipop I want to use setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN). It turns out such background (square)

```
menuItem.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN);
```

[image]

How to make this background rounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `DrawableResource` using [layer-list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList). To make background rounded create new `DrawableResource`, let's name it `ic_pen_rounded` and put the next code into this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#8df"/>
            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_pen" />
</layer-list>
```

Then just use this `Drawable` when creating `MenuItem`:

```
menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Pen")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_pen_round)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
```

And also you can get rid of lines where you setting background of the `VectorDrawable`:

- `menuItem.getIcon().setTint(color);`
- `menuItem.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN);`

You can set icon background in your `ic_pen_rounded.xml`, in the next line:

```
<solid android:color="#8df"/>
```

This is my result:

[image]

**UPDATE - How to change icon background color at runtime**

1. Add `id` to your `ShapeDrawable` inside `layer-list`:

   ```
   <item
       android:id="@+id/background">
       <shape android:shape="oval">
           <solid android:color="#8df"/>
           <size
               android:width="100dp"
               android:height="100dp" />
       </shape>
   </item>
   ```
2. Get `menuItem` icon:

   ```
   LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) menuItem.getIcon();
   ```
3. Find background `item` by id and set color:

   ```
   GradientDrawable icon = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.background);
   icon.setColor(Color.RED);
   ```

Comment: I gave each layer-list item id and trying to change the color like this:
`LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(PhotoEditorActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_pen_rounded);
GradientDrawable font = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.font_item);
ont.setColor(color);`
Сolor does not change, how to change it programmatically?

Comment: @Interrobang it's because you get `Drawable` for resource changes it and didn't set. I've updated my answer.